# Adding in blank rows in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame

```
data<-data.frame(Type=c("A","B","D","D","E","E"),
                 Ratio=c(5,6,3,3,4,4),
                 Number=c(65,74,43,34,23,12),
                 Letter=c("P","K","M","M","N","B"),
                 Season=c("Fall","Spring","Winter",
                          "Summer","Spring","Winter"))
> data
Type Ratio Number Letter  Season
A     5      65     P       Fall
B     6      74     K       Spring
D     3      43     M       Winter
D     3      34     M       Summer
E     4      23     N       Spring
E     4      12     B       Winter
```

Where I would like to add new rows to the 'Types' that are only used once(A and B). 
I would like to add a bow beneath each of there rows that contains the same type,ratio, and number for the one above it, but NA for letter and season. 
I have used

```
group_by(Type)
```

to start

I would want my final data frame to look like this

```
Type Ratio Number Letter  Season
A     5      65     P       Fall
A     5      65     NA       NA
B     6      74     K       Spring
B     6      74     NA       NA
D     3      43     M       Winter
D     3      34     M       Summer
E     4      23     N       Spring
E     4      12     B       Winter
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert "empty" rows (filling up) in data frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021595/insert-empty-rows-filling-up-in-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: @erasmortg I think it's distinct from that particular question, though I'm sure something similar to this is out there...

Answer (score 2):

Another `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(data)[, if (.N == 1L) 
                c(Number = list(Number), .SD[1:2, .(Letter, Season)]) 
              else .SD, 
by=.(Type, Ratio)]
#    Type Ratio Number Letter Season
# 1:    A     5     65      P   Fall
# 2:    A     5     65     NA     NA
# 3:    B     6     74      K Spring
# 4:    B     6     74     NA     NA
# 5:    D     3     43      M Winter
# 6:    D     3     34      M Summer
# 7:    E     4     23      N Spring
# 8:    E     4     12      B Winter
```

Comment: I guess by = Type & Ratio might depart from expected behavior if Ratio varies within Type

Comment: @Frank, from the Q: *"I would like to add a row beneath each of there rows that contains the same `type, ratio`"*.

Comment: I mean that the count will be wrong. The condition is that there be one row for that Type. If we have for type A two obs like (A,5) (A,6), then the OP's condition will not be met (since .N is 2), but yours will be met for each of those obs (since they each have .N of 1).

Comment: It's not clear to me if OP's data can have `A, 6`. In any case, the change is quite straightforward, and I'll let the OP figure it out for him/herself.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) #1.9.5+
setDT(data)
data<-setkey(rbindlist(list(data,data[,if(.N==1).SD[,!c("Letter","Season"),with=F],by=Type]),fill=T),Type)
> data
   Type Ratio Number Letter Season
1:    A     5     65      P   Fall
2:    A     5     65     NA     NA
3:    B     6     74      K Spring
4:    B     6     74     NA     NA
5:    D     3     43      M Winter
6:    D     3     34      M Summer
7:    E     4     23      N Spring
8:    E     4     12      B Winter
```

Answer (score 1):

Base package:

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(table(data$Type))
d2 <- data[data$Type %in% d1[d1$Freq<2,1], 1:3]
d2[, c("Letter", "Season")] <- NA
d3 <- rbind(data, d2)
d3[order(d3$Type), ]
```

Using `dplyr` and base package. I've refined my solution based on the use of `bind_rows` by Nick Kennedy. So I don't need to create my NA columns.

```
library(dplyr)
d1 <- data %>% group_by(Type) %>% summarize(count = n()) %>% filter (count<2) 
d2 <- data[data$Type %in% d1$Type, 1:3]
d3 <- bind_rows(data, d2)
d3[order(d3$Type), ]
```

Output:

```
  Type Ratio Number Letter Season
1    A     5     65      P   Fall
7    A     5     65   <NA>   <NA>
2    B     6     74      K Spring
8    B     6     74   <NA>   <NA>
3    D     3     43      M Winter
4    D     3     34      M Summer
5    E     4     23      N Spring
6    E     4     12      B Winter
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-line `dplyr` solution (though printed over multiple lines for clarity):

```
data %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  do(if(nrow(.) > 1) . else bind_rows(., select(., Type, Ratio, Number)))
```

And if you'd prefer nested pipes to `do`:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  bind_rows(.,
    filter(., n() < 2) %>%
    select(Type, Ratio, Number)
  ) %>%
  arrange(Type)
```